# Android doesn't sigin in using Firebase Auth in Google Sigin

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I generated my keystore using "Generate Signed Bundle" in Android Studio.
I got my SHA1 and SHA256 using keytool

My app isn't yet published in the Google Play.

I'm logging:

```
registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
...
        println(result.resultCode)
        val signInResult = result.data?.let { Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(it) }
        println(signInResult?.status)
...
```

The result in Logcat is:
`0`
`Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}`

MainActivity

```kotlin
package io.ionic.brooksfield
...
    lateinit var googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient
    private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
...
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
...
        val googleSignInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail().build()
        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this@MainActivity, googleSignInOptions)

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnLogin)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            val intent: Intent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
            resultLauncher.launch(intent)
        }

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        val firebaseUser: FirebaseUser? = firebaseAuth.currentUser
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            println(firebaseUser.displayName)
        }
    }

    var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val signInAccountTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount> = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result.data)
            val data: Intent? = result.data
            val txt = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtResult)
            txt.text = data.toString()
        }
    }
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.15' apply false
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'io.ionic.brooksfield'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.ionic.brooksfield"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 33
...
    }
...
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.5.0'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
}
```

google-services.json

```json
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "169490533010",
    "project_id": "fusapp-2cbfb",
    "storage_bucket": "fusapp-2bcfb.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:169480533010:android:20b1a56e5bb5b57a89764b",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "io.ionic.brooksfield"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "169480533010-5ui..57ae.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "io.ionic.brooksfield",
            "certificate_hash": "6332f3f57f44c8da45cebbd3d1cea2872a9ae5a4"
          }
        },
        {
          "client_id": "169480533010-f4..f0.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSxBcMnITszPIucOZRe4qqPRQdUhPyDsWawY"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "169480533010-f4...f0.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

Firebase io.ionic.brooksfield console:
[image]

Google Android App console:
[image]

Google Web App console:
[image]

I tried using the old way and I got status code 10:

```kotlin
        val btnLogin = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnLogin)
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener {
            val intent: Intent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
            startActivityForResult(intent, 11)
        }
...}

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == 11) {
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            handleSignInResult(task)
        }
    }

    private fun handleSignInResult(completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
        try {
            val account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
            println(account.displayName)
            println(account.email)
        } catch (e: ApiException) {
            println("signInResult:failed code=" + e.statusCode)
        }
    }
```

I tried other solutions, for example, using Web Server Id:

```kotlin
val googleSignInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)  
.requestIdToken("169480533010-f4..f0.apps.googleusercontent.com")  
.requestEmail().build()
```

Comment: Are you authenticated in Google on the device? Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).

Comment: Thanks @AlexMano, I need to have a bundle published in google play? I have a Google Play app in draft in internal testing, it's enough?

Comment: I was referring to the fact that when you try to sign in using Google, you have to be authenticated on the device with a Google account.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint.

I was using: `keytool -keystore debug.keystore.jks -list -v`
To get the SHA-1 but in the Google Play Console, in left menu Release -> Setup -> App Integrity the SHA-1 was different.

I needed to use inside Android Studio:
`gradle signingReport`

And configured the SHA-1 in Google Cloud Console -> API & Services -> Credentials
And in Firebase console -> Android App